# Update variable when break the while

Tags: java, variables, while-loop, break

**My goal:** ONLY do 'stuffT' when boolean `a=true` AND `b=true`.

```
class myClass
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        boolean a=true,b=true;
        while (condition)
        {
            if (conditionA){a=false;break;}
            else if(conditionB){b=false;break;}
        }
        if (a==true && b==true)
        {
            //do stuffT
        }
    }
}
```

But after meet `break;` value of `a` and `b` still `true`. Causing my `do 'stuffT'` happened (when it should not, if `a` or `b` has `false` value)

I've tried to set `a` and `b` to `null` first then update their value when `break` the `while` like this:

```
boolean a,b;
while (condition)
{
   if (conditionA){a=false;break;}
   else if(conditionB){b=false;break;}
}
if (a==true && b==true)
{
    //do stuffT
}
```

But I got *Error:* **variable a might not have been initialized**

Also had tried to `break;` first, then update their value like :

```
if (conditionA){break;a=false;}
else if(conditionB){break;b=false;}
```

But got *Error:* **unreachable statement** (for updating variable after `break;`)

So how can I achieve **my goal**?

Comment: Are you sure that `conditionA` or `conditionB` happen once ? put a `System.out.println("a");` just after `a=false` and same for b, to be sure one of the 2 happen

Comment: where condition come from, Did you sure that while loop even entered? and also conditionA and conditionB

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sure `conditionA` or `conditionB` happen, because in my 'actual' code, `break;` notify that "already meet conditionA" or "already meet condtionB"

Comment: Can you please add the `print` and test ;) Sure that it is not `condition` that stop the loop ? Because if you go out of the loop only because of conditionA OR conditionB you'll never do "stuff", so `condition` may be false at  moment

Answer (score 0):

Your code (first one) is okay. Check it by replacing both `conditionA` and `conditionB` with hardcoded `true` value. Debug the procedures which evaluate your conditions (`conditionA` and `conditionB`).
Also check that both of `conditionA` and `conditionB` can ever be true, otherwise you're at risk of not been getting out of your loop (depends on how you evaluate `condition`)

Comment: Debug proposition is NOT an answer

Comment: @azro my answer is 'The code is okay'. It meets the goal declared in the question. What's is wrong with it?

Comment: He said he has a problem, i don't see any word of your post dealing with this, you just said "your code seems good", that does not provide any information to the whole page, and will help no one after

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code. I just assumed the conditions. If you set both a and b to true it skips the while and go to the if loop

```
public class testClass {


        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            boolean a=true,b=false;
            while ((!a && b) || (a && !b)) {
                System.out.println("a or b is false");
                if (!a) {
                    a=true;
                    System.out.println("a is false");
                    break;
                }
                if (!b) {
                    b=true;
                    System.out.println("b is false");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (a && b) {
                System.out.println("Both are true");
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: You've just change the look, NOT an answer

Comment: I think the goal is to "do stuff when when both are true" which is what I have depicted via my code

Comment: yes but apparently the problem is other, you give the same code ^^